# Will the Black Flash make an appearance in season 3?

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash

I have seen images from the sets of *The Flash* season 3, showing a man in a black costume. Is there any secured information if this character is supposed to be the Black Flash known from the comics? Will we see three speedsters in season 3?

[image]

Comment: The black flash you have above is an avatar of death and after some timey whimey stuff actually Barry in the comics. Basically the Time Wraiths from season 2.

Comment: the producers have given us an objective answer to this question, I think it can be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, there have been three speedsters confirmed for season 3.

- Grant Gustin as Barry Allen, the Flash.
- [Keiynan Lonsdale as Wally West, the Kid Flash](http://tvline.com/2016/07/12/wally-west-kid-flash-photo-the-flash-season-3-spoilers/)
- [Todd Lasance as The Rival](http://tvline.com/2016/08/23/the-flash-season-3-todd-lasance-cast-rival/)

Lasance's character, wearing a black suit, was previously unidentified, but [people were able recognize the actor](https://twitter.com/canadagraphs/status/753126203498921984/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw), who wasn't Teddy Sears (Zoom/Jay Garrick/Hunter Zolomon/Black Flash)

[image: The Rival? Black Racer?]

So what of the rumors about The Black Flash?

[EW asked this of the producers recently](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/08/19/spoiler-room-blindspot-originals-svu).

We *will* see The Black Flash - we just don't know exactly when yet.

> *Are we going to see Black Flash on The Flash in season 3? — Peter*
>
> Potentially. “Obviously we did that on purpose,” EP Andrew Kreisberg says. “We love working with Teddy [Sears]. He’s such an amazing actor and amazing person, and was so much a part of the success of this show last season. There aren’t any immediate plans for that, but you can’t keep a good Black Flash down, so I’m sure we’ll be seeing him in the future.”

Comment: A detail that does not change anything for Black Flash: Savitar has also been announced to be in the third season. And Reverse-Flash appears in the trailer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Black Flash has been confirmed and in fact as of now, already has made an appearance on the Flash. Now, for the specific episode, I'll be posting that information under spoiler protection:

> Into the Speed Force, Ep. 16 during the time that Barry is being "tested" by the Speed Force so he can rescue Wally.